# Thread does not run unless awaited

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm unsure whats going on here. If I do

```
 Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("abc");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }).Wait();
```

This will execute normally and program works fine etc. But if I do

```
 Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("abc");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        });
```

Nothing happens!

In the second case the thread just does not start.  Im using visual studio, last thing I did was work on an async method and then intellisence crashed or something. Since then I cannot start a new thread in my app unless I wait for it, which defeats the purpose.

If i try to start a thread like in the first case in a different project, it works fine.

Anyone have an idea whats wrong?

**Edit**: Ok I made a new button on my form and added a click event. I put this code in a new method in a different class:

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("abc");
        });
```

When called from that class by the new button's event handler it works fine.

However if i call this same method from an older button it does not fire although the button event itself fires. So threads created in that button's event handler method do not run...

Well I guess that solves it.

Comment: I find this hard to believe. Are you sure it's not just that your app is finishing before the task has actually started? Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: When the visual studio crashed, button's click event, which you set through Properties window of the button, was not set properly. When you restarted, the code stayed but button. `button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);` did not. Happened to me a few times.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Task.Run is like create a new theread which will be running in theread pool. I mean the thread will execute in background.
So you need something to block the main thread like you did using the command wait from task class.